# MySQL обычный SELECT завершается неудачей

Tags: mysql, select

Есть база данных на MySQL, в ней таблица из 24 полей, обычная, MyISAM, всего лишь 2,628 строки

Через API время от времени делаются запросы к этой таблице через PHP/mysqli, где обычный SELECT по одному полю ищет одну строку

В большинстве случаев происходит два варианта:

- Запись найдена, происходит работа с записью и все в порядке
- Запись не найдена (ее действительно нет в таблице) и в работе отказано

На днях поступили жалобы, что клиенты обращаются к этой таблице, и им выдается результат - запись не найдена, я смотрю лог сохраненных запросов, беру оттуда значение поля для поиска, и запись с таким полем нахожу. Причем при создании записи проставляется время, и на момент запроса эта запись в таблице точно была

Запрос к базе делается очень просто:

```
function element_GetByNumber($number) {
    $data = db_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `number` = '" . db_escape($number) . "' LIMIT 1;");
    if ($data && $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        return $row;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Сама функция `db_query` описана еще проще:

```
function db_query($query) {
    if ($GLOBALS['DB_LINK']) {
        return mysqli_query($GLOBALS['DB_LINK'], $query);
    } else 
        if (db_connect()) {
            return mysqli_query($GLOBALS['DB_LINK'], $query);
        }
    return false;
}
```

Подключение к базе в виде `db_connect()` открывается в начале работы и закрывается по завершению, то есть отсутствие подключения можно исключить. Линк до базы сохраняется в глобальную переменную и не меняется, база одна

При такой просто те есть *нотариально заверенные скриншоты* от клиентов и подтверждение в логах, что элемент, который есть в таблице и должен быть найден, возвращает "не найден", то есть NULL

Никак не могу понять, в чем дело, и почему в некоторых случаях обычный SELECT может давать сбой

Возможно с подобным кто-то уже сталкивался, какие могут быть варианты, куда смотреть, что проверять, что исправлять?

На данный момент я добавил лог по результату запроса с выводом самого результата и последней ошибки SQL в надежде, что они прояснят ситуацию. Что еще можно предпринять для отлова этой бяки?

UPD: Лог дал дополнительную информацию. При подключении mysqli_connect выдает false. Похоже, проблема была как раз в отсутствии подключения. Добавил в лог вывод ошибки подключения, жду результата

UPD2: Выяснил, что mysqli_connect выдает false молча, mysqli_connect_error() пустой и mysqli_connect_errno() равен 0 после подключения. Все очень плохо. Добавил временный костыль с 10 подключениями с паузой в 10мс и еще больше логов. В логах MySQL ничего нет, в логах Apache тоже ничего нет. Призрак

Comment: `то есть отсутствие подключения можно исключить` - нельзя без проверки соответствующего кода. Может быть вы при ошибке подключения тихо игнорируете проблему. И сразу же: только в очень редких случаях ситуации запрос вернул ошибку и запрос не вернул данных равнозначны. В большинстве же случаев запрос с ошибкой должен выбрасывать исключение (mysqli это делать может сам, но только если заранее попросить)

Comment: Не хотелось бы вместо скриншотов с "Элемент не найден" видеть скриншот с исключением MySQL конечно, но за совет спасибо, оставлю на крайний случай.

Comment: Вам никто не предлагает выводить какие-либо сведения об исключении пользователю. Эта информация нужна в логах. А пользователю - нормальное сообщение, что что-то пошло очень сильно не так, как предполагал разработчик.

Comment: Да, я понял, уже добавил в лог, смотрю

Answer (score 1):

Ха-ха, похоже, придется

```
do {
  $res = mysqli_connect();
  usleep(...);
  ...if (...) ... break;
} while (!$res);
```

Как в клиенте на голых сокетах.

Comment: Практически скопировали мой костыль ) Да, уже 10 часов и ни единого разрыва. Это помогает, но хотелось бы докопаться в итоге до причины такой шляпы, а не затыкать ее костылями